# Using Log4j2 in static method

Tags: java, log4j2

I want to using logger in my static method.

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class ErrorHandler {
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ErrorHandler.class);

    public static String returnErrorPage(String error, String className) {
        logger.error(className + ": " + error);
        return Page.ERROR;
    }

}
```

**Problem:**
*Can not resolve method `getLogger`*

**Questoion:**
How use `log4j2` in static method?

Comment: Use `LogManager.getLogger` not `Logger.getLogger`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo can use with `LogManager`, for example:

```
private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(ErrorHandler.class);
```

Here you have an example: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html

Answer (score 1):

The Logger class in Log4j2 does not have a static `getLogger(Class<?> c)` method.

You are probably looking for the `LogManager`.

[Logger Javadoc](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/Logger.html)

[LogManager Javadoc](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-api/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/LogManager.html#getLogger--)